# Exporting SSRS Report to PDF in MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, export-to-pdf

Yes , I want to Export SSRS Report to the PDF and Return it from my action, **I do not have any Report Viewer**.Please Suggest me how can i achieve this. so far i have done this

```
    public void SqlServerReport()
    {
        NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = nwc;
        string reportURL = "http://servername/ReportServer/reportfolder/StateReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";
        Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData(reportURL);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now);
        Response.BinaryWrite(pageData);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Above code throws an exception

```
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

My Questions are
1) Am i going in right direction?
2) Is There any Better Alternative to achieve this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I Corrected the Above Code and now its Working

```
    public ActionResult GetPdfReport()
    {
        NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = nwc;
        string reportURL = "http://someIp/ReportServer/?%2fReportProjectName/ReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";
        return File(client.DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf");
    }
```

i do not found any other alternative than this to export SSRS Report in MVC without using ReportViewer.

Comment: How come I don't get a 401 by using an <iframe tag, the report displays correctly?  But, when I use your code I get the 401?  I'm using the user/pass that the datasource uses.   Do I need to create new user/pass or use impersonation?

Answer (score 1):

try not specify the domain like this:

```
NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```