# Download a Report Server pdf fro C# code

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reporting-services

So I have followed the code from this site([Exporting SSRS Report to PDF in MVC Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833889/exporting-ssrs-report-to-pdf-in-mvc-action)) and various others, but nothing seem to work. I want a link on a web page in mvc that will download  a report as a pdf. The url works fine web I browse to it but I keep getting this error: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." in mvc. This is my code at the moment:

```
public ActionResult Download()
        {
            var url = "http://xxxx/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fxxx+xxx%2fxxx+Report&rs:Command=Render&CellNumber=";

            NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = nwc;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            string reportURL = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", url, Cellphone, "&rs:Format=PDF");
            return File(client.DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf");
        }
```

When I remove the `"&rs:Format=PDF"` part it authorizes, but then the app fails after that. 
Please Help.

Comment: are you sure the final you url you construct acceptable by the pdf service?

Comment: Use this link http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2015/07/print-export-ssrs-report-in-aspnet.html